# Cumulative Sum in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image]

Please help to get cumulative sum on net sales where Posting type = "Posted"

Only for Posted, we need cumulative sum

Need cumulative sum on net sales where posting type = "Posted"

Answer (score 2):

Use this measure:

```
running total = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[net sales]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Data'[month no]),
        ISONORAFTER('Data'[month no], MAX('Data'[month no]), DESC)
    ),
    Data[Posting type] = "posted"
)
```

[image]

In case your sample data is not fully representative(?) and you also have different years, add this calculated column first

```
StartOfMonth = DATE(Data[year], Data[month no], 1)
```

and change the running total formula to

```
running total date = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Data'[net sales]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Data'[StartOfMonth]),
        ISONORAFTER('Data'[StartOfMonth], MAX('Data'[StartOfMonth]), DESC)
    ),
    Data[Posting type] = "posted"
)
```

[image]